# SPSite.Audit.GetEntries does not retrieve 'Item creation' events

Tags: sharepoint-server, auditing, audit-log-reports

I am creating a system to collect all events for all site collections for reporting later.
I notice that none of the events that are returned from `SPSite.Audit.GetEntries()` method, say anything about adding an item to a list (discussion board in my case)
I only see 'update' once with item type Document and once List.

Is there a way to identify the creation of the items in the audit?

Answer (score 1):

It's normal behavior, The SharePoint Audit Setting doesn't have **Item / Document Creation Event**

**The events that audited for documents and items within site collection includes the following:**

- Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists or viewing item properties
- Editing items
- Checking out or checking in items
- Moving or copying items to another location in the site
- Deleting or restoring items

**Unfortunately**, the Item Created event is not listed in the SharePoint audit events! so you will not find any item creation entries returned by `SPSite.Audit.GetEntries()`

---

**To Check Site collection audit settings**, Go to

- Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Site collection audit settings.
- There is no any event for Item created!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the SPWeb.GetChanges method which gives the complete changes (add/edit/delete) done on the site or a particular list.

For a code snippet please check - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461643.aspx

Comment: Cool! did not know it existed. I only want changes to list items but can't find examples to SPChangeItem . Do you know of one?

Comment: Nice But how do I get the User ID of the user who made the change?  SPChangeItem does not have a User property and the Token has numbers may be one of the is the user